# Maximize iFrame (so it appears to be the request page)

Tags: html, css, iframe

how can I (cross-browser compatible) maximize an iFrame so that it appears to be the page in the URL bar even though it is served from a different server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this ought to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
 <head>
  <title>Test page!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
     html, body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
     }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <iframe src="page.htm" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:** You could just hide the scrollbars of the page, with the HTML and scroll=no directive
(that solution should be multi-browser)

**Edit 2:** Now even XHTML proof ;)

**Edit 3:** And finally w3 validator ok
(be sure to add scroll=no in the BODY if you run in Internet Explorer compatibility problems)

Comment: That's what I did, but I get a 2nd set of scroll bars like that.

Comment: And: In Firefox the height 100% doesn't work, it only gets like 300px high approximately. Don't know why.

Comment: Okay it looks like the XHTML Transitional Doctype caused the problem. Weird. It restricts the height of the iframe to some arbitrary value across browsers.

Comment: Same with XHTML Strict. This is really strange. It only works if I leave out any doctype!?!!

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript with the event body load to set iframe height & width to window height & width.

For example in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initIframe();
});
function initIframe() {
    $("iframe").height($(window).height());
    $("iframe").width($(window).width());
}
```

Tested on FF, IE and GC

Comment: This should work, but CSS can accomplish this with no scripting.

Comment: I tested CSS but I'm not sure it's full cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

You could set the width and height of the parent page's `html` and `body` tags to 100%, as well as the `iframe` tag that contains the page you want to load.