# How to maximize iframe to cover entire page in Mozilla and IE both

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to maximize the iframe window so that it make a illusion that its a page not an iframe in Mozilla and IE both.

I have found an article on Stack Overflow: **[Maximize iFrame (so it appears to be the request page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252412/maximize-iframe-so-it-appears-to-be-the-request-page)**

Applying this it solves the IE issue but not of Firefox.

Comment: Apart from phishing, is there any valid use for such a trick? No offense, I'm just curious.

Comment: I am just wondering why you need this.

Comment: @Ankur to rephrase what Thomas said, Why do you need to do this? Using iframes in this way can be easily abused.

Comment: Ok Thomas I want you to know where I want to use it basically I downt want to show the query string to the end user i use changing it to session is very length task so i simply add the pages on iframe thats all

Comment: In the page i make use of simply anchor tags its quite easy to bind the query string variable

Comment: Could you use ajax to do this instead?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're using the wrong strategy to solve your problem, since a user could just right-click on the page to view its URL and querystring. Additionally, your full URLs would show up in a google search if Googlebot indexed them. To make it plain and simple, security by obscurity = bad security. There are plenty of ways to share state between pages without passing it through the querystring, such as using the session or database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me in FF 3.5

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
 <head>
  <title>Test page!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
     html, body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
     }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <iframe src="page.htm" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a security exploitation.  Do not actually attempt this.  Even if your intent is not malicious anything that comes through that iframe can carry potentially malicious code.  The fastest growing vector of malicious code form JavaScript is through advertisements with crappy and easily compromised code that loads through an iframe.

I urge you to reconsider your objectives and try something else.  ANYTHING ELSE.

Comment: I agree, and suggest ANYTHING ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

I have a site that uses an iframe.  In Firefox I can just right-click the frame and say show this frame only and the URL shows in the address bar.

Do not count on this trick to hide the address of your content.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a legitimate usage for this.  I have a web application where I have to keep a track of a nominated client id for each window that might be created.  I can't use cookies, because that only tracks on client, and I'm loathe to pass the client id through all my URLs, even the ones that don't need it.

So I'll be wrapping the main application view port with a iframe container that will use JS to set/get this client id in the parent/top container.